# React Router 4: Render paragraph based in the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was thinking about react router 4 and I found myself with a question and I want to know what you guys think about it.

I have an header that shows two texts, one is in the left side and another in the right side. The text in the right side is rendered conditionally, if I'm in the '/:id' route, the right side text renders 'edit company', but if I'm in the '/new', the right side text renders 'add new company'.

But where is my question?

Till now I was doing like that:

```
<span>{this.props.match.path === '/new' ? 'add new company' : 'edit company'}</span>
```

But this is the best way to do it? Someone asked me why to not use `<Route>` Component from react-router 4, and I wasn't able to answer. I don't feel myself comfortable using a Route to render a text in the right side of my header, seems a lot of effort.

What do you guys think about it?

Comment: It's OK the way you are doing, but keep in mind that if you change your `Route` structure you'd have to change this line as well.

If you have more differences between the two pages I'd recommend a `Route` since your code can become a big mess. Consider using the same `Wrapper Component` for both `/new` and `/:id` and pass props down.

Everything really depends on your project.

Comment: What he is trying to suggest is something like this:


```<Route exact path="/new" component={() => <span>add new company</span>} />```


`<Route exact path="/:id" component={() => <span>edit company</span>} />`